# How to sort PHP array depending on the position of a string in each element?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, sorting

In JavaScript an array can be sorted depending on the position of a string in each element, using something like this:

```
arr = arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.indexOf(str) - b.indexOf(str);
});
```

Can a similar thing be done to PHP array, so that it is sorted depending on the position of string in each element?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will be helpful for those who will come. I propose an improvement to @DannyPhantom answer.

Any value which doesn't contains the searched string, will be put at first place. `strpos` returns `false` when the searched string is not found, thus it needs to be handled, because as we all (should) know, `false == 0` and `strpos()` returns 0 when the searched string is found at the beginning.

As the [PHPDoc says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

> **Warning**
>
> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.

So, here is my solution

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) use ($str) {
    $idx_a = strpos($a, $str) === false ? PHP_INT_MAX : strpos($a, $str);
    $idx_b = strpos($b, $str) === false ? PHP_INT_MAX : strpos($b, $str);
    return $idx_a - $idx_b;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to do pretty much the same thing using [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). Anonymous functions will work as well.

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) use ($str) {return strpos($a, $str) - strpos($b, $str)}) //code is not tested, though should work
```

`$str` is the string you are searching for and `$arr` is your array

NOTE: `use` will only work in PHP 5.3+